# Unexpected Parquet FIle Size

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, parquet

I'm very new to the Spark scene so please be patient if I'm making an obvious error here.

I'm writing some parquet files out after reading and transforming from a source containing a significant amount of data. The data is read in successfully as confirmed by display commands. My issue is when I write the parquet files to the destination folder they're of size 0 (after being partitioned by two of the columns).

This is the write command:

```
df.write \
.partitionBy([partition1], [partition2]) \
.mode("overwrite") \
.parquet("dbfs:[destination]")
```

After executing, I'm then seeing this in the log4j output:

> 21/06/20 10:35:02 INFO NativeAzureFileSystem: FS_OP_CREATE
> FILE[destination/partition1/partition2/_started_4885624909327698290]
> Creating output stream; permission: rw-r--r--, overwrite: true,
> bufferSize: 65536 21/06/20 10:35:02 INFO NativeAzureFileSystem:
> FS_OP_CREATE
> FILE[destination/partition1/partition2/_started_4885624909327698290]
> Closing stream; size: 0

Does anyone know why the size might be 0?

Comment: look at the sub directories.